# Show some proofs in the set $M=\{a+x+\sqrt{a-x+x^2}|x\in N\}$

Tags: radicals, rational-numbers

**The question**

Let $a \in (0, \infty)$ and the set

$$M=\{a+x+\sqrt{a-x+x^2}|x\in N*\}$$

Show that:

a)if $a=1$, then the set $M$ contains exactly $2$ rational numbers

b) if the set $M$ contains at least $2$ rational numbers, then the number $a$ is rational

**The idea**

a) if $a=1$ then we have to solve $1+x+\sqrt{1-x+x^2}=y$, where $y$ is an rational number

$\sqrt{x^2-x+1}=y-x-1$ and because $y-x-1$ is an rational number we get that $\sqrt{x^2-x+1}$ should also be a rational number $=> x^2-x+1$ is a perfect square

$x^2-x+1=k^2$

Maybe I can demonstrate it by using a quadric formula...I don't know.

b) For point b we have to show that if $x^2-x+a=k^2$ has at least $2$ rational solutions, then $a$ is rational...

I don't know what to do forward. I hope one of you can help me. Thank you!

Comment: Multiply $x^2-x+1=k^2$ by 4 and get $(2k)^2 - (2x-1)^2 =3$

Comment: Or note that the discriminant is $(2k)^2-3$, which must be a perfect square. (Which is equivalent to above comment)

Comment: What is $\Bbb N*$?

Comment: @DS I don't know what to write the set of nonzero natural numbers...this is what is means....

Comment: Okay. Can you solve the first part by the above 2 hints?

Comment: @DS yeah... the problem is point b...

Comment: @DS Reading what i wrote above i think I made a false affirmation. We should show that if $a+x+\sqrt{a-x+x^2}$ have 2 values for which the number its rational, then a is rational... i just supposed that a is already rational, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second part (since you've already solved the first):
Let the 2 values of $x$ be $m$ and $n$. Then:
$$(a+m + \sqrt{m^2-m+a}) - (a+n + \sqrt{n^2-n+a}) \in \Bbb Q \iff \sqrt{m^2-m+a} - \sqrt{n^2-n+a}\in \Bbb Q$$
Note that $\sqrt{m^2-m+a} - \sqrt{n^2-n+a}$ is non-zero since $x^2-x$ is increasing over the naturals. Then:
$$\frac{n-m}{\sqrt{m^2-m+a} + \sqrt{n^2-n+a}} \in \Bbb Q \iff \sqrt{m^2-m+a} + \sqrt{n^2-n+a} \in \Bbb Q$$
Adding, $\sqrt{m^2-m+a} \in \Bbb Q$, so this forces $a$ to be rational.